# Save/download Google maps icon image

Tags: google-maps

I am very new to this, so please forgive me if this question is stupid. I am using a custom Google Map in my website. I have 2 layers and each layer has a different type of business. I am using 2 different icons/markers selected from the standard Google Maps options to differentiate between the two types of businesses.

I would like to create a map key explaining to customers what the different markers indicate - but I cannot find these markers as images on the net, and I can't figure out how to save or download them from the map itself. So my question is: Is there a way to download and save the actual marker/icon image, so I can re-upload it elsewhere on the page and create a map key? I realize that the Google Map already has a simple key (if you know to click on it to see it) but I was hoping to create something with more text/explanation, that is more obvious to customers when the page loads.

Here is the url for the map I'm referring to: www.washingtonlavenderassociation.org/map

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

http://map-icons.com/

```
var marker = new Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46577, 153.02303),
    icon: {
        path: SQUARE_PIN,
        fillColor: '#00CCBB',
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '',
        strokeWeight: 0
    },
    map_icon_label: '<span class="map-icon map-icon-point-of-interest"></span>'
});
```

or from docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I'm confused about the links and code you shared - they seem to be focused on my adding my own icons to the google map. That's not what I want to do, so I apologize if I just don't understand. Am I supposed to search for the icons on those sites somehow, and then download there? Again, I apologize if I'm being dense - but I don't have my own icons I want to add. I want to use the two google icons/markers I already have selected, and just need to download a .jpg or .png of the markers so I can place them elsewhere on the page. I don't want to create a new marker,